# Web.Config changes not picked up by FilterConfig MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

So in My FilterConfig.cs under App_Start, I have this code:

```
 public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            var enableFilter = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableLogActionFilter"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(enableFilter)
                && enableFilter.Trim().Equals("true", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                filters.Add(new LogActionFilter());
            }
        }
```

and in the Web.Config, I have an entry under AppSettings, I have a key **EnableLogActionFilter** which toggls the feature on or off.

When I run the website via IIS Express on my local box, the changes are picked up, Application_Start fires in Global.asax.cs and FilterConfig adds the MVC action filter to the Global Action Filters, and works fine.

However, when I run under Local IIS, the changes get picked up from Web.Config, but Application_Start/FilterConfig is not fired again? I tried recycling app pool but that did not help.

The same thing happens on the deployment server. The changes can be seen in the Configuration Editor section of the website in IIS, but the MVC action filter is not added, because no log entries are made. No exceptions logged in the Event Viewer of the Deployment Server either. Has anyone encountered this before? I have spent last 2 hours on this, and not getting anywhere.

Comment: Your app runs in it's own folder with it's own apppool? What does `appcmd list site` and `appcmd list app` output? (appcmd is in the folder %windir%\system32\inetsrv)

Comment: Yup, own app pool. Found out the issue. I was missing a config entry in the database config table. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I am a muppet. Then I found out that I was missing a config entry in the database table, which acts as a second on/off switch apart from config file. So now scripting the database change :)